# Why "-fno-inline" brings so bad performance in clang?

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

We use clang to compile IR code, then execute the IR in some place.

For some reasons, we add "-fno-inline" in compile options, which brings very bad performance. Before the IR code takes less than 1ms, after open "-fno-inline", the IR code takes more than 20ms.

From my understanding, inline only eliminate the cost of function callings(such as rbp/rsp push/pop, call/ret).

Am i right? Any suggestions?

Comment: Inline eliminates that cost, but may also open the road to further cost savings. For example, when the two functions are merged, the register allocator has better knowledge of what the called function does, and may be able to avoid spilling to main memory in the calling function.